# Navigation Slam gmapping multiple laserscans

Tags: slam, navigation, gmapping, xtion, laserscan

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, i'm trying to create a map with two asus xtion on my turtlebot2. They are mounted back to back in the middle of the turtlebot. One to the front and one to the back. After bringing up the turtlebot and the gmapping_demo i can see both laser scans in RVIZ, so this seems to work. I can also see the messages published on /scan from both cameras. The problem is now, slam_gmapping only creates the map basing on one camera as i can see in RVIZ. Is there a possibility to create a map basing on multiple laserscans? So, i think the problem is the gmapping node only uses one laserscan from one camera.
I've already found this discussion on this topic:
http://answers.ros.org/question/9294/using-multiple-laser-scanners/?sort=latest#sort-top
Maybe there are some new insights.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/201003/navigation-slam-gmapping-multiple-laserscans/) by [fabs](https://answers.ros.org/users/21368/fabs/) on ROS Answers with karma: 76 on 2015-01-14

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Today i found the following very interesting project from the iralab. They developed a laserscan toolbox for merging laserscans. In the example they got another assembly of the scanners, but maybe it can be modified.
I think the problem point is the destination_frame. I think i have to create a "virtual" camera with 60° in the front and 60° in the back. Correct me if i am wrong.

1. https://github.com/ros-perception/slam_gmapping/issues/17
2. http://arxiv.org/pdf/1411.1086.pdf

---

Originally posted by [fabs](https://answers.ros.org/users/21368/fabs/) with karma: 76 on 2015-01-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fabs](https://answers.ros.org/users/21368/fabs/) on 2015-01-21**:
This is the right solution :). I've got not enough points to mark it as the correct answer.